# Is there a way to change font color of a specific word in a string, in extendscript for after effects?

Tags: adobe, extendscript, after-effects

I can change the font color of the entire text layer successfully, but I cannot find a way to change the color of a specific word in a string.

For e.g. 
In this string "Trying to learn extendscript for after effects", I want to change the color of "learn" only.

```
var mySourceText = 
currItem.layers.byName('line04').property("ADBE 
Text Properties").property("ADBE Text Document");
var myTextDoc = mySourceText.value;
myTextDoc.fillColor = [0.5,0.5,0];
mySourceText.setValue(myTextDoc);
```

But this would change the color of the entire text layer.

Is there a possible solution to it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Nope! You can't set these properties for specific pieces of text in a text layer.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible –it's kind of [a hack using text animators](https://community.adobe.com/t5/after-effects-discussions/automatic-color-change-for-specific-words/m-p/9875940#M60010), but works.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).