# How to set individual font color using extendscript

Tags: extendscript, after-effects

I have created a paragraph text in after effects using Extendscript

For example i have a text "HI". I need to give color for "H" as red [1,0,0] and "I" as green [0,1,0].

I have checked everywhere ,. where i can find out that i can change the text color in whole rather than individually ! is there anything that can be done?

I need to change color of each and individual characters using script

Comment: Have you used extendscript toolkit to inspect the TextDocument object that represents the script. If you dig into its properties you may be able to find where the colours are stored for each character.

Comment: I think it is not possible

Comment: @stib: Yes but i couldnt get what i wanted

Comment: I have tried and not been able to find a way. [So have others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48749423/is-there-a-way-to-change-font-color-of-a-specific-word-in-a-string-in-extendscr)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like it's not possible. The text in a text layer is a `TextDocument` object, and when you look at the AE scripting guide it says

> **TextDocument fillColor attribute**
>
> textDocument.fillColor
>
> **Description**
>
> The text layer’s fill color, as an array of [r, g, b] floating-point values. For example, in an 8-bpc project, a red
>   value of 255 would be 1.0, and in a 32-bpc project, an overbright blue value can be something like 3.2.
>
> *NOTE: If the text layer has different fill color settings for each character, this attribute returns the setting for the first character. Also, if you change the value, it resets all characters in the text layer to the specified setting.*
>
> **Type**
>
> Array [r, g, b] of floating-point values; read/write.

The important bit is the *Note*. The same thing applies for all the text attributes like fontSize, fill, stroke &c., &c..

So for some reason you can't access the style attributes for anything but the first character in a line of text. Are you annoyed? I am. Perhaps log a bug with Adobe—it will be completely futile, but you might feel better.